# How do I create a textbox with prefilled text that can be edited?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

----SOLVED----

I'm creating a textbox in Angular/Ionic that has prefilled text from the previous page. 
I have a Notes page that comes right before the current page, and asks the user to document any notes they'd like.
On the current page, I want there to be a notes box with the notes that the user last entered. From here, the user should be able to edit these notes if necessary. I've created two separate notes pages because this last page acts as a summary page before the user submits the data to the server.

I've already tried using the placeholder option, where I set the placeholder to the notes the user enters on the first screen, but all of that data disappears as soon as the user touches the box again. I want the text to still be there and editable.

I also tried putting the notes inside of , but that is not editable.

```
<div class="notesBox">
        <ion-textarea id="prefill" [(ngModel)]="notes" (ionChange)="updateNotes()"></ion-textarea>
</div>
```

```
this.prefilledNotes = this.dataService.getNotes();
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("prefill")).placeholder = this.prefilledNotes;
```

Comment: Hi Julian. Glad you found a solution to your question. It would be useful for other users who may face the same issue if they could find a clear answer. I would suggest you to revert the question back to its original form, and that you write a "real" answer yourself, and that you accept this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [(ngModel)].

```
<div class="notesBox">
        <ion-textarea id="prefill" [(ngModel)]="prefilledNotes" (ionChange)="updateNotes()"></ion-textarea>
    </div>
```

```
this.prefilledNotes = this.dataService.getNotes();
```

By first setting the ngModel property value to whatever the user already entered, it populates the textbox with that value. It also is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("prefill")).value = this.prefilledNotes;
```

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: Nothing appeared

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which has a variable for notes and instead of manipulating data using document.getElementById you can directly get and set that variable wherever you need